# How to install hp support assistant in elementary os Juno 5.0?

Tags: drivers, hp

How to install hp support assistant in elementary os Juno 5.0?
I wanna know how can I install hp support assistant from http://www.kernel.org/

or

If there's any other way to install?

Answer (score 0):

the HP Support Assistant seems not to be available for Linux.
Check https://www8.hp.com/de/de/campaigns/hpsupportassistant/hpsupport.html
and also https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Support-assistant-for-linux/td-p/6718492

Do you need a special Driver for a Device like a Printer or a Bios Update? With BIOS Update there seems only the way to Install Windows and run it from there. Another Solution described here https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/How-do-I-update-the-BIOS-in-Linux/td-p/6498633 is to create a USB Bios Recovery Drive and Update it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after BIOS update, many HP laptops and desktops can do a flash update from the BIOS itself using DOS images located in a separate folder of the BIOS file. It is poorly documented but it works, you can even easily extract the required files from the Windows executable file.
Just copy the content of DOS folder on the USB stick and select it from the flash update menu of the BIOS.